# Accessing other service using an REST Call inside Docker Compose

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, docker-compose, httpclient

I think I got a simple question and have not found a solution on the web yet. I have 1 project with multiple **solutions** in it. I have put them all into a **docker compose file**. Each service has his own port: http://localhost:8081, http://localhost:8082 and so on...

I have service A on port http://localhost:8081 and service B on port http://localhost:8082.

I try to call an endpoint in **service B** from **service A** with HttpClient. The default way of making a Rest call. I call http://localhost:8081/ServiceA/testcall.

I tried to call an external API : **https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts** and this works. But when I try to call my own endpoint I get the following error:

**Internal Server Error 500**

I debugged it but do not get a more detailed message.

I tried:

1. Make rest call to **http://localhost:8082**
2. Different ways of making a rest call

**SERVICE A CONTROLLER**

```
namespace A_service.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ServiceAController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceARepository _serviceARepository;

        public ServiceAController(IServiceARepository serviceARepository)
        {
            _serviceARepository= serviceARepository;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> JustASimpleGetCall()
        {
            // This call works fine
            return("Hello World");
        }
        [HttpGet("testcall")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomethingFromOtherService()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service-b:8080/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // HTTP GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("ServiceB/simplefunction");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return Ok("Succesful");
            
        }
```

**SERVICE B CONTROLLER**

```
namespace B_service.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ServiceBController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceBRepository _serviceBRepository;

        public ServiceBController(IServiceBRepository serviceBRepository)
        {
            _serviceBRepository= serviceBRepository;
        }

        [HttpGet("simplefunction")]
        public IActionResult ServiceBFunction()
        {
            // To simplify, we just return a
            // Declaration of the array
            string[] str1;

            // Initialization of array
            str1 = new string[5]{ “Element 1”, “Element 2”, “Element 3”, “Element 4”, “Element 5” };
            return Ok(str1);
        }
```

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  serviceA:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: serviceA/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  serviceB:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: serviceB/Dockerfile
    environment: 
        - SERVER_URL=http://service-b:8080
    ports:
    - "8082:80"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get to serviceB from serviceA the url is http://serviceB:(application port) it seems that your application goes on port 80 (at least that is what written inside the docker-compose.yml). if you can get to serviceB from your computer like localhost:8082 that means that the port is configured to 80.
if the port in the application is configured to 8080 that means the port you'll need to write is 8080.

Comment: But how does it know that I mean the 8080 port from serviceB and not serviceA? Since both services refer to :80?

Comment: firstly i do need to ask if it helped the problem.
secondly think that each service is a docker container by it self and the docker-compose gives each service a DNS that is the name of the service that is why i said  http://serviceB.
moreover if you want to get to serviceB from your OS and not from serviceA you configured to go to 8082 and not 8080, so you would want to send a request to localhost:8082.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks! I did not know what you meant at first.

Comment: cool, can you please select my answer as the correct one?